# Web SMTP Server(foo.com) will not send mail to exchange server which is also(foo.com)

Tags: exchange, smtp, http

I think I understand this problem fully, but I do not know how to approach it or where to go in terms of troubleshooting.

I've got my one domain http://foo.com that runs a Zen Cart installation that needs to be able to send emails to users(order confirmation, password reset). This works fine to send to any other domain BUT foo.com.

I'm running a locally hosted exchange server that is foo.com, and we can send and receive email just fine.

If I run *tail -f /usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog* I recieve this error:

```
Apr  1 10:08:51 foo qmail-local-handlers[25824]: Handlers Filter before-local for      qmail started ...
Apr  1 10:08:51 foo qmail-local-handlers[25824]: from=
Apr  1 10:08:51 foo qmail-local-handlers[25824]: to=actual_exchange_user@foo.com
Apr  1 10:08:51 foo qmail-local-handlers[25824]: cannot reinject message to 'anonymous@foo.com'
Apr  1 10:08:51 foo qmail: 1270141731.583139 delivery 32410: failure: This_address_no_longer_accepts_mail./
Apr  1 10:08:51 foo qmail: 1270141731.584098 status: local 0/10 remote 0/20
```

I understand that the foo.com SMTP service doesn't have any account but the one that is used to authenticate mail being sent, so of course, I understand why it's saying 'this address no longer accepts mail'.

My question is, how can I get the foo.com(web) SMTP service to handle emails meant for my exchange server(user@foo.com) or how do I handle the mail that needs to be sent to our exchange server? Is this something to do with MX records?

Thanks in advance

A

Answer (score 1):

Configure qmail so that it doesn't think it's the SMTP server for foo.com.  The information on how to do this should exist in the [qmail](http://www.qmail.org/top.html) documentation, but I've never used it and can't find anything easily on that page so can't point you at the right part.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. I have a few more domains on that web server and instead I just used another domains account to verify the SMTP emails.

Thank you for the thought in the right direction.